# Why does installing .Net MAUI app give me different results on different iPhones?

Tags: .net-maui, maui-ios

I created a .Net MAUI app (iOS) and built it with Azure DevOps. Our tester downloaded it from AppCenter and installed on his iPhone. He was not able to open it with the following error:

"My App" Needs To Be Updated. The developer of this app needs to update it to work with this version of iOS."

But I used the app on two different iPhones, one of which had the same iOS version as the tester's phone (15.7), and they both work without problem.
What can be causing the issue?
And how is it supposed to be updated?

Comment: Are you both downloading the app from the same source and are you both using the same iOS, if yes then this could be something serious if not then there is some issue while creating the build from Devops.

Comment: @FreakyAli Yes, we both download from the same source, and use the same iOS version.

Comment: What kind of provisioning profile are you using on the build server? Maybe you're using the wrong one

Comment: @ewerspej How can I determine the kind of provisioning profile? I use task InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1 on the pipeline. And if the profile is wrong, how come my the same app works on my two phones?

Comment: If the build server uses a development profile and your devices are registered as development devices, then this could be a possibility. The problem just sounds familiar.  I'm not a DevOps expert, I would need to look it up myself regarding the setting of the correct profile.

Comment: @ewerspej Yes, it is a development profile, and our devices are registered in the same way. Still not clear what causes this inconsistent behavior.

Comment: @DavidShochet Could it be that the other devices UUID is not present in your Provisioning?

Comment: @FreakyAli No, I definitely added it.